# Generic type factory

Tags: c#, generics, factory

Let say I have a general class for Fruit Trees, and some specified trees:

```
    abstract class FruitTree
    {
        public abstract String getFruitName();
    }

    class AppleTree : FruitTree
    {
        public override String getFruitName()
        {
            return "Apple";
        }
    }

    class OrangeTree : FruitTree
    {
        public override String getFruitName()
        {
            return "Orange";
        }
    }
```

And what I want to do, is create a fruit trees factory:

```
    public static int APPLE = 0;
    public static int ORANGE = 1;

    public class FruitFactory
    {
        public List<FruitTree> getYummyFruitTrees(int type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case 0:
                    return new List<AppleTree>();
                case 1:
                    return new List<OrangeTree>();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

But C# doesn't allow to do that. How can do that anyway? I don't care if there is list of AppleTrees of OrangeTrees, I just want to get list of FruitTrees.

EDIT:
I have to edit my question, because the example was too simple:

This example was given for simplicity, but it gives essence of the issue - my problem is that I have an processing algorithm class, which uses smaller classes as processing element. For example, Matrix, which uses specific type of cell (BaseCell).

```
    public class Matrix<T> where T : BaseCell
    {
        (...)
    }
```

I have to develop one of forks of this algorithm which uses a big part of base code, but uses also extedend cells, for example:

```
    public class ExtendedCell : BaseCell
    {
        (...)
    }

    public class SuperMatrix : Matrix<ExtendedCell>
    {   
        (...)
    }
```

And, finnaly, I have a runner for this algorithm, which manages running it on theads etc.

```
    public class AlgRunner 
    {
        Matrix<BaseCell> algToRun;

        public AlgRunner(Matrix<BaseCell> alg)
        {
            algToRun = alg;
        }
    }
```

I just want to use some of it's base class fields / methods and I don't need to know, which fork of algorithm it is, so i HAVE to use inheritance instead of implementing interfece. In java, where I have much bigger experience, it's not a problem, but I have no idea how to achieve it here.

Comment: You can't return a `List<OrangeTree>` as a `List<FruitTree>` because... it isn't one. You can add an `AppleTree` to a list of fruit trees by definition... but not to a list of orange trees. [Read up on variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee207183.aspx). What exactly are you actually trying to achieve here? Why not just instantiate a `List<FruitTree>`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern may be useful to consider here.

Comment: If you really need to return a list of some extending type, maybe you can use type constraints on a generic method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?  Something like `public List<T> getYummyFruitTrees<T>() where T : FruitTree`

Comment: While you can construct a method like this if you use a covariant interface (instead of a List), I strongly discourage you from deciding which type of object to create based on an int.  By all means return an `IEnumerable<FruitTree>` from your factory methods but make separate methods for creating AppleTrees and OrangeTrees - it'll be easier to maintain and you won't risk a rogue null infiltrating your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from the additional information that you have added that you can't do exactly what you are looking for with concrete classes.  You can, however, do it with interfaces provided that you don't need variance on both output and input types (i.e. covariance and contravariance) simultaneously.

You can construct:

```
public class IMatrix<out T> where T : BaseCell
{
    T Cell { get; }

    ....
}
```

Here you can have output arguments of type T but no input arguments of type T.

or

```
public class IMatrix<in T> where T : BaseCell
{
    void FunctionOnCell(T cell);

    ....
}
```

Here you can have input arguments of type T but no output arguments of type T.

I think, for your use case, the covariant (out) example is the one you're looking for.

Assuming you used the covariant interface, your algorithm runner could then accept an argument of type `IMatrix<BaseCell>` even if the actual concrete class was a `Matrix<ExtendedCell>`.

```
public class AlgRunner 
{
    IMatrix<BaseCell> algToRun;

    public AlgRunner(IMatrix<BaseCell> alg)
    {
        algToRun = alg;
    }
}
```

For more details on creating covariant and contravariant interfaces, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx

Comment: That looks nice! Thank You for Your help!

Answer (score -3):

this one should help

```
 public IEnumerable<FruitTree> getYummyFruitTrees(int type)
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return new List<AppleTree>();
                    case 1:
                        return new List<OrangeTree>();
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Maybe. Assuming the asker needs an `IEnumerable`.... which may not be the case and can't be determined from the question.

Comment: you can use IEnumerable to return list of generic childs

Comment: But the caller is left with a compile time type of `IEnumerable`. Which may not be sufficient.